# How to automate opening files one by one and then prompt to delete?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, shortcut-keys, automation

Full disclosure I am a total noob, I started using ubuntu 3 months ago, loving it so far.

Here is the problem

I have a folder containing over 800+ images, I want to go through each one of them one by one to see which ones I want to keep and which ones to delete.

Doing this through GUI is tedious.

The current sequence of actions that I have to perform is the following

Open the image file, File Opens in the Image Viewer

I look at the image & decide if I want to keep it or not

I close the Image Viewer by pressing ALT + F4

Then I select the file & Press SHIFT + DELETE to permanently delete the file.

Then I repeat the same for the remaining files

Having to do this for 800+ files will take too long, how to automate it?

Ideal sequence would be

The first file in the directory opens in the Image Viewer, I get prompted to either keep the image or delete it, by pressing Y to delete or N to keep it, after I press Y or N, then the next image opens after that and just repeat the same for all the files.

I remember a few years ago, had a similar issue, I was using windows 10 back then, had to go through a large number of PDFs & my colleague who was more technically capable than I am made a .bat file to automate the process, all I had to do was to just decide if I want to keep the PDF or delete it by pressing Y or N on the keyboard.

How to do this in ubuntu Terminal?

I tried getting help from the infamous ChatGPT, it generated a script, I tried it but it doesn't run , But as I said in the beginning I am a total noob at this so I must have a made a mistake, I have no Programming experience, I know some html, but thats about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this simple script:

```
for f in *.jpg; do eog "$f"; rm -i "$f"; done
```

You might need to install `eog`:

```
sudo apt install eog
```

---

However, I don't think this is a good idea. Most of the times you need to find the best 1 or 2 pictures out of a set of pictures, and you don't know which one to keep unless you saw all of them.

With e.g. `geeqie`, you can delete photos by simply pressing <kbd>Del</kbd> while watching, and you can go back and forth to decide which picture(s) to keep.

Comment: No, I have no problem looking at all the images, just manually opening the images through GUI  and closing window with alt+f4 then shift + delete is the tedious part, just want each file to open automatically then prompt to keep or delete and than automatically open the next file, so I dont have to press any other keys,  I just have to keep my fingers on Y & N as the images open one after the other, it would not take me long to decide which ones I want to keep, It would only take me 2 seconds to decide to hit Y or N

Comment: so then, the script should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot this solved it for me, I was able to get through all the images much faster, manually opening, closing, deleting would have easily taken an hour, I was able to get it done in 26 Minutes with the script above. Thanks